# PHP - Create a Schedule table in relation to time

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, html-table

I'm doing a school project and I have to create a schedule from an array. I already sorted the array by day & time. I know how to create a simple table and insert the data - but I wanted to make a more defined table in relation to time:

The array for Monday looks like this:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [courseID] => comp275 [lectureID] => gg [day] => monday [stime] => 12:15 [etime] => 15:16 [term] => winter [year] => 2014 ) [1] => Array ( [courseID] => comp345 [lectureID] => ss [day] => monday [stime] => 18:20 [etime] => 20:30 [term] => winter [year] => 2014 ) )

I want the table to be like this for column "Monday"

[table type http://4.ii.gl/mtHVQN.png](http://4.ii.gl/mtHVQN.png)

This is my code at the moment (its a bit broken but i haven't figured out how to do what i really want yet.)

```
<table>

                <tr>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                </tr>

                <?php getMonday($Array); ?>

                </table>
```

Function :

```
foreach($Array as $MA)
    {
        echo
                "<tr class='success'><td>".
                "Start-Time :".$MA["stime"]." "
                ."<br><br>".
                "Course :".$MA["courseID"]." "
                ."<br><br>".
                "End-Time :".$MA["etime"]." "
                ."</td></tr>";
    }
```

Gives me this :

[table type2 http://2.ii.gl/Q1Dx-x.png](http://2.ii.gl/Q1Dx-x.png)

Comment: So what is your issue/question? Is it to create the time column, the data, the column background/style, or something else?

Comment: To make it like in the first picture ,  empty space before , after and in-between the courses for the amount of time bet. them etc... I was thinking of dividing the column every 5minutes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cells in your day colum, you could create `div`s for each class and change the height based off the time. For example -

```
$curr_time = strtotime('08:00'); //beginning of the day

foreach($Array as $MA) {

    // create a blank div if it does not equal $curr_time
    if(strtotime($MA['stime']) != $curr_time){
          $empty_size = // get size for difference between $MA['stime'] and $curr_time
          echo "<div style='height:{$empty_size}px;'></div>";
    }

    // create the div for the class time
    $div_size = // get size for difference between $MA['etime'] and $MA['stime']
    echo "<div class='success' style='height:{$div_size}px;'>".

            // your data
            "Start-Time :".$MA["stime"]." "
            ."<br><br>".
            "Course :".$MA["courseID"]." "
            ."<br><br>".
            "End-Time :".$MA["etime"].
            // end of your data

         "</div>";

    // change the $curr_time to $MA['etime']
    $curr_time = strtotime($MA['etime']) ;
}
```

since this is a school project, I won't give you all the code / full working example, just this sample code/idea. You would need to find a way to determine the height of the `div`s based off the difference in time. Hopefully this helps.